# BizTalk Orchestration - One input message to two different BizTalk Maps

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I want to create an orchestration that allows a message to be received and for it to go through two different maps, one after the other. Which shapes would be required for this?

My idea was to use 'Parallel Actions' then have two 'Transform' shapes under each (With one having a 'Delay' shape so that this specific one follows), however reading up about 'Parallel Actions' seems to imply that the message will go to one path or the other, not send the same message to both direction.

How can I have the input message going through two BizTalk maps using Orchestration? What are the appropriate shapes to use?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

- Apply two maps sequentally with 2 Transform Shapes:

1) Source Message > Map1 > Destination Message 1

2) Source Message > Map2 > Destination Message 2

- Send the Source Message to 2 different Send Ports, each one with one map configured.

Comment: Do the first option here.  In this case, the Parallel Shape won't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have two outbound maps. The input for your second map would be the output of your first map?

If so: you can just put two Transform shapes after each other. There is no need for a parallel actions shape. 
Configure the Transform shapes to use the appropriate mapping and the mappings will be executed one after the other.

The other approach is to create a pipeline component capable of executing an `XslCompiledTransform`. Then, create a custom pipeline where both components are chained after each other and use that custom pipeline in your send port. Then you do not even need an orchestration (if no extra business logic is needed).

Up to you to make the correct decision, based on your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you but the question didn't get across clearly. I have two outbound maps but I want the input message being applied to both to produce two separate messages. The same input message on both maps. How would I tackle this? :)

Comment: The same way actually, just select select the same input message for the second transformation.

Comment: The other answer from felixmondelo is the right one then. I got confused with the 'one after the other' in your question.